# Using includes and data binding for reusing layout does not work

Tags: android, layout, data-binding, include

I managed to add a parameter to my includes so that I can reuse a layout with slightly different configuration. But it does not show in the preview of Android Studio (I do not know if Android is able to do this) and I also have problems inflating it. I do not want to connect it to an activity because I want to create a bitmap of the view so I need to inflate and draw it manually.

Layout for inclusion:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable name="myText" type="String"/>
    </data>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/months"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{myText}" />
 </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Used here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <include
                        layout="@layout/counter_4_1"
                        bind:myText="@{`Hello World`}" />
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

This worked without data binding:

```
View checkIds = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
((TextView) checkIds.findViewById(viewId)).setText(text);
int specWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0 /* any */, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        checkIds.measure(specWidth, specWidth);
        checkIds.layout(0, 0, checkIds.getMeasuredWidth(), checkIds.getMeasuredHeight());

        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( checkIds.getMeasuredWidth(), checkIds.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        checkIds.draw(c);
```

With data binding I tried

```
View checkIds = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context),Tools.getLayoutResource(context,countdownSettings.countdownStyle), null,false).getRoot();
```

I also enabled dataBinding {enabled = true} in app build.gradle.

But the data is not shown on the view.

Comment: Does this line `Tools.getLayoutResource(context,countdownSettings.countdownStyle)` returns you layout resource id?

Comment: yes, it gets it from a text string

Answer (score 0):

Make one more variable to pass String in your included child layout

Your include Layout should be like:

```
    <data>
        <variable name="myText" type="String"/>
    </data>
     <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

               <include
                   layout="@layout/counter_4_1"
                   bind:myText='@{myText ?? ""}' />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Check for null `@{myText??""`

Let me know if still any issue.

Comment: the null pointer exception was just because I did not surround some other views with <layout>. So DataBindingUtil is loading the view now but the text is still not being displayed. I figured out that you are using a lambda operation with "??". I probably need to activate lambda in my gradle file to get it working. But Android says that lambda is outdated. Is there a way without lambda? And will this solution show also in preview? I guess not.

Comment: I also used bind:myText="@{@string/hello_world}" and this compiles well but still it is not showing in the view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same data variable in your main layout as well, where you are calling the

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable name="myText" type="String"/>
    </data>
    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <include
                 layout="@layout/counter_4_1"
                 bind:myText="@{myText}" />
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

and then you can pass the same variable i.e from your Activity.

```
public class UserDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        YourMainLayout mBinding = DataBindingUtil
                .setContentView(this, R.layout.your_main_layout);

        String myText = "Hello World";

        mBinding.setMyText(myText);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to set the variable in the parent activity. So the included layout can be slightly different like bigger text, different font color etc.

Comment: sorry i meant parent layout, not activity .